# SQL Server 2008 R2 restore error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I restore database backup in SQL Server 2008 R2 , I get this error message .

[image]

How can I solve it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server database backup restore on lower version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183139/sql-server-database-backup-restore-on-lower-version). And the error message includes some very specific instructions on what to do, so it isn't clear what problem you're having.

Answer (score 3):

Your backup comes from a SQL Server **2008 R2** (v10.50.1600) installation, and you're trying to restore to SQL Server **2008** (v10.00.1600).

This is **NOT SUPPORTED** and cannot be done. If you have a backup from SQL Server **2008 R2**, you need to restore to **2008 R2** (or newer) - you cannot go back in time.

Answer (score 1):

Versions between production and your destination are different. I think you can't solve this easy, maybe to try to make scripts for creating database and objects, and to use SQL Import/Export tool to transfer data from source to destination.

Also, you can go to production database, right click on it, and choose `Generate scripts` option to create whole database with entire structure. Even, you can use this tool for export data and, later, import them, but for large amount of data, this step work unpredictable.