# Create SQL Server 2008 Backup from 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

I've created a Backup of a Database on a server with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I wish to restore this onto a server that is running SQL Server 2008.

I've received the error:

> "The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.4000.
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
>   version 10.00.5500."

Is it possible to produce a version 10.00.5500 compatible backup from 10.50.4000.

If not what other options do I have, or other ways to create the database.

I have tried to use the `Copy Database` task, but also received errors.

Comment: It's not possible. 2008R2 is newer version and as with any two different versions of SQL Server. It's not possible to restore backup from newer to older version.

Comment: There is a same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183139/sql-server-database-backup-restore-on-lower-version and you can find a lot of info online - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2675/why-cant-i-restore-a-database-to-an-older-version-of-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. At least, you won't be able to use the backup to restore on an older version.

Nenad Zivkovic provided a good link and there are several ways out of this situation listed:

- Upgrade the older version of SQL Server to be at the same level as the newer SQL Server.
- Script out the objects from the newer database and then usp a bcp process to extract the data from the newer database and import it into the older database.
- Use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to build an SSIS package to move the data (it will move the data only).
- Build a custom SSIS package to do the data move.
- Use replication to move the data from the newer database to the older one.
- Use some other form of scripting, such as with PowerShell, to keep the databases in sync.

(Source: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2675/why-cant-i-restore-a-database-to-an-older-version-of-sql-server/)