# downgrading sql database

Tags: sql-server, data-migration

I have my database in  MS SQL 2014. I need to migrate the data from this server to MS  SQL 2012 server.I have database size of about 10 GB. I have tried Backup/Restore, Attach/Detach, export/import and creating script but did not work for me because of size and limited user right.None of the solutions worked from
[SQL Server database backup restore on lower version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183139/sql-server-database-backup-restore-on-lower-version)

Comment: Well - first thing to solve is limited user rights. If you don't have access - you need it or somebody with access should do it.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I have access otherwise I cannot use backup/restore.

Comment: Downgrading a database isn't supported. This isn't data *migration*

Comment: You can script the DDL and then use the import export wizard for the data.