# What happened to the SQL Server Database Migration Wizard?

Tags: migration, azure-sql-database

The "SQL Server Database Migration Wizard" aka SQL Azure Migration Wizard previously located at http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/, but it is gone.

I attempted to search via Google for its new home, but I cannot find it.

Does anyone know where this tool has gone?

Answer (score 12):

It is replaced with Data Migration assistant..

> Data Migration Assistant (DMA) enables you to upgrade to a modern data platform by detecting compatibility issues that can impact database functionality on your new version of SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. It recommends performance and reliability improvements for your target environment. It allows you to not only move your schema and data, but also uncontained objects from your source server to your target server
>
> DMA replaces all previous versions of SQL Server Upgrade Advisor and should be used for upgrades for most SQL Server versions (see below for supported versions).

**References:**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/datamigration/dma/

Comment: Thank you. I installed the DMA, but it is missing the ability to migrate a database from SQL Azure to an on premises SQL Server instance.  The original SQLAzureMW had this capability.

Comment: When I try to use a SQL Azure DB as the Source with the DMA tool, it says: 
 Invalid source server details were specified for the migration.
Server 'xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net' has an unsupported database environment for this operation: 'AzureSqlDatabase'. It must be one of these: 'OnPremises'.

Comment: To migrate a database from Azure SQL Database to an on-premise instance of SQL Server, export the cloud database as bacpac file through the Azure portal and then import the bacpac file on your on-premise instance using SSMS

Comment: Thank you, Estienne !   This is exactly what I needed. In fact, it can all be done from within SSMS.  Awesome !

Comment: Data Migration Assistant is also unable to migrate from SQL Server to Amazon RDS because it requires the sysadmin role, which RDS doesn't make available.

Comment: Why on earth have they replaced a tool that allowed me to get my Azure database and put it local with one that can't?

Comment: @hokkaidi This looks like a security feature?  With AMW you could get a database from an Azure instance so long as you had SA rights.  Now, you have to create a bacpac and download that - which requires authentication in the Azure portal.  I suspect that this is the reason a lot of people are not happy... even if they are technically safer

Answer (score 5):

You can now find it here: https://github.com/adragoset/SQLAzureMigration

(I searched for a long time too before I found it.)

That code did not work out of the box for me. Took me about 30-40 minutes to get it to build. But seems to work fine once I got it to build and run.

Comment: Could you provide some information with why you could not get the build to work and what you had to change?

Comment: Sorry @Kasaku, I should of course have provided some more information but was short for time at the moment.

I think I needed to switch the SMO from the old package that comes installed with SQL Manager to the new SMO that is on NuGet. As there has been a few breaking changes in SMO, I had to fix the code for that.

On top of that there was some validation that didn't work and simply wasn't relevant any longer, so I had to remove that.

I think that was about that. Good luck getting it to work.

Comment: Has anyone got a binary of this to download? Just to save me some time that's all.

Comment: Sorry @RichardGriffiths. As I describe I of course have a working copy of this, but at the moment I simply have no time to understand the legal and license implications of just giving downloads to others. I have made an entry on my mental to-do list to fork the GitHub project and make it work there. (But, sorry, don't hold your breath.)

Comment: Did anyone else successfully get this built and is able to share?