# Is it possible to save a SQL Server 2016 database into a lower version?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, database-backups

I created a database in SQL Server 2016, but I need to save it into a lower version and be able to open it in SQL Server 2014. Is it possible?

Comment: I really appreciated for the help. I am newbie here in sql

Comment: You can find techniques for migration the data here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/6183139/1080354

Comment: Yes Generate Script with lower version

Comment: Thank you for the tips abdul qayyum

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. The reverse one is possible - to restore database backup from one edition to latter one.

You can also perform on place upgrade of your SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Thank you for your responds really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but it requires some administration. You will have to enable replication, and create a snapshot publication of the database, with your SQL 2014 server as your subscriber.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the tips will try this,